# Delaying load of d3 element within loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This fiddle delays loading of a line :

http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3557/

This works as expected. I'm attempting to load this line multiple times, so I replace :

```
drawLine();
```

with

```
while(true)
  drawLine();
```

But why does this cause the function `drawLine()` to be invoked continually and the delay is ignored. How to modify fiddle code so that the function is not called without a delay ?

fiddle code :

```
drawLine();

function drawLine(){
var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1200)
                .attr("height", 1200)
                .attr("text-align", "center");    

var labelLine = svgContainer.append("line")
                .attr("x1", 10)
                .attr("y1", 10)
                .attr("x2", 30)
                .attr("y2", 30)
                .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                 .style("visibility", "hidden")
                .transition()
                .delay(1500)
                .style("visibility", "visible")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.delay(1500)` is non blocking, hence you loop will call `drawline()` continously without any delay. What you are looking for is [timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) :

```
function drawline(){
  //your stuff
  setTimeout(drawline, 1500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(true) drawLine();` is an infinite loop, which will crash your browser as the delayed drawings pileup. Try limiting the number like so : `var i = 10; while(i--) drawLine();`.

Note, since computers are fast, all the lines will be drawn at pretty much the same time - i.e. 1.5 seconds after running your script. If you want to have them drawn in sequence, try setting timeouts, with increasing delays.